# Get value from select box through ajax to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a select box where i pass the value through ajax to a mysql statement.
I need to make it a bit more intelligent, so i dont have to hardcode all the values from the select box

The HTML select box is:

```
<select>
  <option value="value1">something</option>
  <option value="value2">somethingElse</option>
</select>
```

I pass the value through ajax with:

```
var opts = [];
$selectboxes.each(function(){
   opts.push($(this).val());
})
```

In my php file i use the value to filter a SQL select statement:

```
if (in_array("something", $opts)){
$where .= " AND region = 'something'";
}
```

If the user selects option 1 with the value `value1` the php file should change to something like

```
if (in_array("VALUE1", $opts)){
  $where .= " AND region = 'VALUE1'";
}
```

Comment: use `id's` and `where in`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) option of where and array_intersect to select only the values that we find in $isarray

```
$isarray= array("something","somethingElse",....)
$is = array_intersect($ops,$isarray)
$where .= " AND region IN ".$is
```

Note: properly sanitize your $opts so you don't have sql injection

Comment: Well. This only make part of my code dynamical. I need to get the value to change two places. I added a last part of code explaining that i want

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values in something variable then you probably store those values in an array and using [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) you can achive desired result.

```
<?php
$opts = Array ('value1','value2','value3','value4');  //select box values which your are passing from ajax call
$somethingArray = Array('something', 'value1','value4'); //value that you need to match / compare

$result = array_intersect($opts, $somethingArray);

$where = '';
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $where .= " AND region = '".$value."'";
}
echo $where;   //Output=> AND region = 'value1' AND region = 'value4'
?>
```

Comment: I have different select boxes i all use for filtering. The value of these select boxes are stored in the array $opts. Right now i have an if statement which has hardcoded values for all options. So if a select box holds 10 different options, i have to hardcode 10 different if statements

Comment: Have you tried my solution?. For your info store 'somethingElse,something,something2' in $somethingArray array. and check

Comment: @user6322087 see my answer

Comment: Yes i tried it, and either i didnt make it work, or it doesn't accomplish what i want. Im not quite sure :S I'm not sure i understand the purpose of $somethingArray. I updated my question to be more specific. Please look at the last piece of code.

Comment: Please check with updated answer. Hope it will help.